# Imprimir números primos no intervalo 0-N

Tags: python

Basicamente o programa deve **verificar e exibir todos os números primos até o valor digitado.** Já fiz um código que verifica se é primo ou não (a verificação tem que ser feita por uma função), porém não sei como exibir os números até o valor digitado.

```
def primo(numero):
    if numero != 0 & numero != 1:
        if numero > 3:
            for i in range(2, numero):
                if numero % i == 0:
                    return False
        return True
    return False
num = int(input("Digite um numero:"))
print("É primo" if primo(num) else "Não é primo")
```

Comment: De uma olhada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+primo e veja se ajuda.

Comment: Obrigado pessoal consegui.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia caro amigo. Pelo o que eu entendi, você pode usar um `for` juntamente com um `range` para isso:

```
max = int(input('Digite um número: '))
for número_atual in range(max):
    print("É primo" if primo(num) else "Não é primo")
```

Espero ter ajudado.